# Работа со временем в Laravel

Tags: php, mysql, laravel

Как правильно делать запросы с `whereDate` в laravel?

Например, есть запрос

```
$data = date('Y-m-d H:i');//Время на сервере
$plan = Plan::whereDate('date_start', '<', $data)->get();
```

Нужно вывести все планы, у которых просрочено время, он выводит

```
1 план - 
Сейчас - 2018-11-21 04:24
План - 2018-11-20 17:30:00
- Все правильно, дата плана уже прошла
```

И выводит еще один план

```
2 план -
Сейчас - 2018-11-21 04:24
План - 2018-11-21 10:20:00
- Получается, что дата плана больше, чем сейчас времени
```

Почему он выводит 2 план?
Или `whereDate` работает только с датой, а часы он не трогает?

Как сделать правильный вывод планов?

Comment: [в документации](https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/queries) говорят о том, что этот метод используется только для сравнения даты, без учета времени. Используйте where

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Используйте Carbon.
Укажите в модели `Plan`:

```
protected $dates = ['date_start'];
```

Далее можно делать выборку:

```
$data = Carbon::now();
$plan = Plan::where('date_start', '<', $data)->get();
```